# letter keys scrambled in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard

Fresh install of 18.04
New keyboard.
All letter and symbol keys are scrambled. Number keys ok.
I can not change settings because I can not enter password.

Comment: A corrupted install? Did you verify the ISO? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview Did you use the official install tutorial? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: You've provided few specifics, is this a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server install? Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop install? 18.04.1? 18.04.2? ... 18.04.6?  Is this a grub password? CLI password?  GUI password?  Have you confirmed the keyboard actually works correctly?  has good connections?

Answer (score 0):

I would fan/mash the keyboard, pressing all keys to make sure nothing is stuck. Then restart into **[single user mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub)** so you can have a command line interface. From there I would expect there are resources online to reset the selected keyboard interface. ([this may help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675476/reset-keyboard-layout-to-default-and-wipe-out-all-earlier-settings))